# How can I rename multi index index values with other values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame MultiIndex:

```
f1  f2  value
2   3   5
3   3   4
4   1   3
    4   3
```

I would like to have an output to replace f2 with :

```
f value
1  A
2  B
3  C
4  D
```

So the output should look like:

```
f1  f2  value
2   C   5
3   C   4
4   A   3
    D   3
```

Can you suggest an elegant way to create output?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`MultiIndex.set_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html):

```
new = df.index.levels[1].map(df1.set_index('f')['value'])

df.index = df.index.set_levels(new, level=1)
print (df)
       value
f1 f2       
2  C       5
3  C       4
4  A       3
   D       3
```

Comment: Respect, you are always so fast. `df.index = df.index.set_levels(df.index.levels[1].map( {1:'A',2:'B',3:'C',4:'D'}),level=1)` Was also working on it